# How to get kernel information

Tags: opencl

I want to get following information about compiled OpenCL kernels - list of types, params order (if possible - with memory and access classifiers). Kernels are build from the sources during run time of app.

Actually, in OpenCL 1.2 already exists appropriate functions for such query - `clGetKernelArgInfo`, but due to project restrictions I have to find way to achieve such functionality using pure OpenCL 1.0 without any extensions.

At present, I am thinking about three approaches:

1. write simple Ansi C parser to get info about kernel's signature directly from OpenCL kernel's source
2. using macros in OpenCL code to mark kernel's arguments for simple in-app parsing (by extending [this idea](http://pimiddy.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/assigning-opencl-parameters-by-name/))
3. define list of the most possible combination of kernel's arguments using macros and class-helpers (due to my project's constrains it is possible to operate under 3-5 common arg-types)

My question: is there any other ways to get info about compiled kernel?

I want to use this info to decrease amount of OpenCL routine in client code by encapsulate calls to `clCreateBuffer`, `clEnqueueWrite`/Read, `clSetKernelArg` in small wrapper, which should check provided params, allocate device side ptrs, copy data from/to hosts and so on.

Comment: I can't imagine any use case for this. Anyway you will have problems to brake this nut(problem) and reach the kernel(args). Why don't just stick to OpenCL 1.2?s

Comment: We use simple vararg function which allows us to call pretty much just setArg(kernel, arg1, arg2, arg3...);. However there is no type checking in our approach. But as for your answer the answer is: No. In OpenCL 1.0 without extensions you don't have any way to get the info. The only error you can get is that the arg size is invalid. Considering that sizeof(cl_int) == sizeof(cl_float) it doesn't really help you to detect any real issues.

Comment: Then use variadic templates (or template overloads on pre-11) instead of varargs to get the proper type information from the host side instead of the kernel side (the host arguments still have to match the kernel arguments, but that applies to the vararg case, too).

Comment: @DarkZeros,
1) I want to simplify my host-side code into something like this:

`OpenCL_Kernel sample_kernel(kernel_name, kernel_arguments_list ...);
sample_kernel.execute([width, height]);`

Based on kernels signature wrapper choose which params should be copied only to gpu, and which should be transfered back, 
which flag should be used during device memory allocation and so on.

2) OpenCL 1.2 is reasonable choice but some users do not upgrade to the latest driver, so I can not relly on this feature in case I want guarantee that my app can be executed in old but stable environment.

Comment: Variadic kernel invocation calls were attempted (twice) in the OpenCL C++ wrapper. It's not an official documented feature of the wrapper, but if you inspect the source, it's there. It doesn't use kernel reflection to do its work, it trusts the caller to know what the parameters are.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd suggest just parsing the kernel instead of using comment markup or macros. It's C99 so fairly parsable, at least for what you need.

Comment: @Dmitry I understand what you need, what I don't really understand is the purpose. Since typically the focus of OpenCL is to target a specific bottleneck operation, with static I/O of variable length. Even in the case you want the kernel to be dynamic, what changes is the algorithm of the kernel not the inputs and outputs.
I agree with Dithermaster that if you still want to go this path, use kernel parser, since the other approach is quite a difficult one. C99 headers are fairly easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

The Khronos [WebCL Validator](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/webcl-validator) gives you the equivalent of clGetKernelArgInfo, including all qualifiers.

The necessary downside is that it's a complete parser, based on Clang/LLVM. It takes roughly the same amount of time to run as a typical OpenCL compiler (not a coincidence), and adds around 10 megabytes to your executable size.